# How do I include jQuery plugins?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to use [Poshy Tip jQuery Plugin](http://vadikom.com/demos/poshytip/). I made a very simple HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>PoshyTip</title>
    <body>
        <center>
            <a href="#" id="tip">Google</a>
        </center>
    </body>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.poshytip.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#tip').poshytip();
    </script>
</html>
```

I have the `.js` file in the same folder as the HTML page. However, I do not see the tooltip. **What am I doing wrong here?**

What's in the console:

```
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
```

That's it.

Comment: The js file is not found, check in web console if the file is loaded

Comment: what is the error showing in console?

Comment: Checked the console. I did not see any errors :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `title` inside your HTML anchor:

```
<a href="#" title="This is a title" id="tip">Google</a>
```

Also, you're missing the CSS file reference of `poshytip`, here I'm using `skyblue` theme:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://vadikom.com/demos/poshytip/src/tip-skyblue/tip-skyblue.css" />
```

You also need to change the jQuery code to load the custom CSS theme by specifying the `className`:

```
$('#tip').poshytip({
    className: 'tip-skyblue',
    bgImageFrameSize: 9,
    offsetX: 0,
    offsetY: 20
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mj5Hx/)**

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the title.

```
<a href="#" id="tip">Google</a>
```

should be

```
<a href="#" title="Google - a search Engine" id="tip">Google</a>
```

The doc says:

> The default browser tooltip that displays the value of the title
>   attribute is replaced with a "poshier" version:

Comment: Okay.. I am new to web development :)

Answer (score 0):

Change link to

```
<a href="#" id="tip" title="Google">Google</a>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/shijin/jguHu/)